# C# Rotate Transform

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can rotate the Panel and Text 90º and it works for me. But rotating 180º doesn't work, I can't see the text. What can I do to fix it?

```
else if (m_orientation == AfyLabelOrientation.TurnedLeft90)
        {
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(0, this.Height - 5);
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(270);

            if (!TextShadow_)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), new RectangleF(Padding.Left, Padding.Top, this.Height, this.Width));
            }
            else if (TextShadow_)
            {
                //Drawing text shadow
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), new RectangleF(Padding.Left + 1, Padding.Top - 1, this.Height, this.Width));

                //Drawing text
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), new RectangleF(Padding.Left, Padding.Top, this.Height, this.Width));
            }
        }
        else if(m_orientation == AfyLabelOrientation.Overturned)//This don't work
        {
            e.Graphics.TranslateTransform(this.Width, 0);
            e.Graphics.RotateTransform(180);

            if (!TextShadow_)
            {
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), new RectangleF(Padding.Left, Padding.Top, this.Height, this.Width));
            }
            else if (TextShadow_)
            {
                //text shadow
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(Color.Gray), new RectangleF(Padding.Left + 1, Padding.Top - 1, this.Height, this.Width));

                //text
                e.Graphics.DrawString(this.Text, this.Font, new SolidBrush(this.ForeColor), new RectangleF(Padding.Left, Padding.Top, this.Height, this.Width));
            }
        }
```

Comment: Could you possibly ask a clearer question? It seems to be more of a statement

Comment: How to make Rotate by 180 work right.

Comment: Probably when you are rotation the object is changing his coordinates, its translating.

Comment: You really should mark some of your questions as answered where appropriate, or at least respond why the answers aren't correct. You have a lot of open questions.

Answer (score 9):

If I got it, you need to translate to the object to maintain its center.

`RotateTransform` always rotates about the origin. So you need to first translate your centre of rotation to the origin, then rotate, then translate it back.

```
//move rotation point to center of image
g.TranslateTransform((float)this.Width/2, (float)this.Height / 2);
//rotate
g.RotateTransform(angle);
//move image back
g.TranslateTransform(-(float)this.Width/2,-(float)this.Height / 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

It may be that what you are trying to rotate is in the left top corner of container. Then, rotation rotates around left top corner of your object, so 180 degrees rotation moves your object outside of view window.

```
________
|text   |
_________
```

is rotated into something like:

```
    _______
text|      |
    ________
```

of course I'm not painting `text` rotated, but just trying to idicate its position. Move rotation point to the middle of text or move text by its width to the right after rotation to end with the text being put in correct place.